# Google Plus One button shows wrong count in Android App(wrong count issue)

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I used [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) to add google plus one button to one of my android apps. But plus one button shows wrong count. Everything i did in the code is the same as with the tutorial. I used it before never got this stupid error. 
Right now my app has been recommended 26 times so plus one button shoud show count as "26" but it shows "13".

To include plus button in my layout i used :

```
 <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
                android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_list_item_padding_left"
                plus:annotation="inline"
                plus:size="standard"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/drawer_textview_paddingtopbottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_textview_paddingtopbottom" />
```

To assign button to a member variable i used :

```
mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
```

As suggested i initialized it in onResume method of my activity using below code :

```
mPlusOneButton.initialize(APP_URL, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

here APP_URL is my app's google play page url, PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE is the activity request code i used it as 0.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

---

in my case, after some days it showed correct g+ count itself. I didn't make any changes in my code because i was sure my code is right according to documentation. Why i got that annoying delay? I don't know, maybe it was related with google servers and updates.

Comment: `I used it before never got this stupid error` --> Please post the code that yields the wrong result. If it worked the first time, it's possible that you are doing something wrong, that's making it yield incorrect results.

Comment: @iRuth posted my code.

Comment: The `PlusOneButton` in your layout file does not have this line --> `xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"`. Could you add it and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Actually i had added it to the beginning of the layout file. i changed its place and added it to plusonebutton layout code but still shows wrong count. Unfortunately still have same wrong count issue. @iRuth

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? mine shows a totally different count and when I press plus one and I go to the app page on the browser it doesn't show me as having done a plus one before.

Comment: @mntgoat Unfortunately problem still goes. Some of developers says maybe it is showing only counts of shared google plus ones. Another problem is that when i change the url to another app(not mine just for testing purposes) amazingly it shows the right count for that app. Interesting!

Comment: Have anyone solved this Issue???????, for Only some links I get this  very less count...

Comment: @VivekWarde in my case, after some days it showed correct g+ count itself. I didn't make any changes in my code because i was sure my code is right according to documentation. Why i got that annoying delay? I don't know, maybe it was related with google servers and updates.

Comment: @AnEnthusiast Thanks for letting us know that it takes a couple of days to show the correct number, but ... Have you used http or https in your app link on Google play? Because each one shows me a different number, and both numbers are way lower than the actual number ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My best guesses are:

1. There is a mistype on the APP_URL. Happens to everyone at some point
2. I don't know if this is a factor or not. The app version number is different with the one on Google Play Store. So it returns the wrong +1 count

Cheers